# Sum sql question - two columns inside are connected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please, is it possible return with one query this result (from table below)?

CountId = 4, SumTime = 60, SumServices = 11 (problem is with Sumtime which is connected with Services)

```
ID      Date        Time Services
6267    2018-07-10  10  1
6846    2018-08-21  5   4
7129    2018-09-11  5   4
7224    2018-09-18  5   2
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? SumTime should be 60? or 25?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But if you actually want some help you need to provide some details. How is the SUM of Time equal to 60?

Comment: How exactly do you calculate `Sumtime`?

Comment: 60 = (10 * 1) + (5 * 4) + (5 * 4) + (5 * 2)

Comment: It is called sumproduct... very helpful when calculating weighted averages and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply the columns when calling Sum

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountId, SUM(time*services) AS SumTime, SUM(services) AS SumServices
FROM table
```

Comment: Jesus, it is so simple. Thanx a lot!